# Why does this white blink + fade effect happen?

Tags: android, animation, transition

Whenever I start a transition (either shared element or not), weird things happen.
Specifically before the transition, a big white blink spreads the entire screen and this is there until the end of the transition (small at the beginning, gets bigger then after the end, it disappears). My activity also fades in (and out) of the screen, even if I change it to another transition animation.

My activity launcher code:

```
ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(), intent, 
      ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity()).toBundle());
```

My styles.xml file :

```
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
```

How can I fix this transition behavior?